# Python loops to check columns

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to check whether column 3 of a tab-delimited file contains a certain word. 
If it does not, it should continue reading. If it does contain the word, it should check column 4. Depending on whether there is content in column 4, the output should be something found or something not found.

I'm not stuck on the second part of this, i.e. checking column 4. My output gives me "something found" when there is in fact no content there.

```
for line in f:
    if line.strip()split("\t")[2] == "word":
        print ("word")
        if line.strip().split("\t")[3] is not None:
            print ("something found")
        else:
            print("nothing found")
```

The file looks like this:

> reference #1   reference #2   notword   content     ...(more columns)
>   reference #1   reference #2   word      content     ...
>   reference #1   reference #2   word      noContent  ...

Comment: can you show a part of your file ?

Comment: What do you think you'll accomplish by doing `for eachLine in f:` inside `for line in f:`?

Comment: @KasraAD, does that edit help?

Comment: @jwodder, I thought it was to read each line, but I took it out seeing it is not necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what is my understanding, you unconditionally test for the 4th item, even when the 3rd is not "word", you should instead put the second `if` inside the 1st one.

1. Loop over the lines of your file
2. Strip and split each line into the elements of the list `items`
3. If there is a third item and the item is equal to the string "word"

   - unconditionally print the string "word"
   - if there is a fourth item, and that item is not the null string, print the string "something found"
   - otherwise, print the string "nothing found"

.

```
 for line in open('data.tsv'):
    items = line.strip().split()
    if len(items)>2 and items[2] == "word":
         print "word"
         if len(items)>3 and items[3] != "":
             print "something found"
         else:
             print "nothing found"
```

*Edit*

Following the OP findings I realized that the default behaviour of `split` is to split on *whitespace sequences*, as it is clearly documented, albeit with a different wording, in the doc string

> ```
> split(...)  
>
>     S.split([sep [,maxsplit]]) -> list of strings  
>
>     Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the  
>     delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit  
>     splits are done. If sep is not specified or is None, any  
>     whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are removed
> ```

This is shown also by the following example

```
>>> a = 'a\tb\tc\t\te'
>>> a.split()
['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
>>> a.split('\t')
['a', 'b', 'c', '', 'e']
>>>
```

to summarize, the OP should use the following code

```
 for line in open('data.tsv'):
    items = line.strip().split('\t')
    # -------------------------^^^^--------
    if len(items)>2 and items[2] == "word":
         print "word"
         if len(items)>3 and items[3] != "":
             print "something found"
         else:
             print "nothing found"
```

Comment: thanks! Actually, I AM conditionally checking 4th item only when 3rd is "word", or at least that is my intention. Should I therefore put the second if inside the first?

Comment: Yes, you definitely must nest the conditionals.

Comment: I indented the second if and else , but my output is still "something found" when there is nothing.

Comment: It's the default behaviour of the `split` method, that splits a string not on each whitespace character but rather on whitespace sequences. For now, change `items = line.strip().split()` to `items = line.strip().split('\n')` and I'll edit my answer to show the difference between the two possibilities.

Comment: thank you very much @gboffi! this world, and i appreciate your explanation!

Answer (score 2):

You have doubly nested loops.

This will loop though each cell and check if the contents are word.

```py
for line in f.readlines():
  for item in line.split("\t"):
    if item == "word":
      do_something()
    else:
      do_something_else()
```

For just the header you can do this

```
header = f.readline():
for item in header.split("\t"):
  if item == "word":
    do_something()
  else:
    do_something_else()
```

You could also use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) python module to parse csvs for you, so you don't have to worry about things like quotes.

```py
import csv
with open('sample.txt', 'rb') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
  for row in reader:
    if len(row) > 2 and row[2]=="your string":
      foo()
```

For interacting with large data tables, the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) module is also very useful.

Answer (score 1):

fIRST OF ALL (I;m drunk answering stakoveflow question from a bar).  read a line. if the line[2] is "word", then chekk if line[3] exists.  If it does .. do what you want.  IF it doesn't .. do someting else lile....

```
f = open("sample.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    line_array = line.split("\t"):
    if line_array[2] == 'word'
        try:
            if line[3] == "what you want"
            do_function()
        exception Exception e:
            print "no fourth columm"
```

Sorry about he bad syntax.. just trying to help

Answer (score 1):

(I used commas instead of tabs to make this easier to see in the answer...)

So you have a file that looks like this:

```
Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4
item1.1,item1.2,item1.3,item1.4
item2.1,item2.2,item2.3,item2.4
```

is that right?

And you're trying to *first* check the value in `itemX.3`'s position, and if that doesn't match what you're looking for, you want to check `itemX.4`'s position?

```
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:  # Loop through each line.
    items = line.split(',')  # Split the line into pieces.

    if len(items) > 2 and items[2] == 'the value you\'re looking for':
      print 'Found it!'
    elif len(items) > 3 and items[3] == 'the value you\'re looking for':
      print 'Found it!'
    else:
      continue  # Go to the next line.
```

That make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish your needs:

```
for line in f:
    if line.strip().split("\t")[2] == "word":
        if line.strip().split("\t")[3] is not None:
            print "something found!"
        else:
            print "nothing found!"
```

Also I noticed other solutions are not specifically looking at the 2nd and 3rd columns, where this one is. Just thought I'd point that out.

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying now. What if the "something" in column 3 could be anything? (i.e. irrelevant what the content there is, just if it has something)

Comment: Thank you! -- This has helped a lot. The only thing is that "something found" is returned when the column is empty, and "nothing found" when it does have content.  I've edited the code above. Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: You need to indent your second if and else statements to be inside the first :)

Comment: I tried that, but the error "unexpected indent" came up before the second if. thanks for your help with a probably basic problem ...

Comment: You're missing a dot in front of  your first split(). Everything else looks fine... just make sure things are indented properly.